# Embed a PS variable in a PS variable

Tags: powershell, variables

This works for me.
$puda_TBList=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql)

But what I want to do is embed a variable in the initial variable name like this.
$($DB)_TBList=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql) where $DB is a variable within a FOR loop and I just can't make it work.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried all of these and got erros.

$($DB)_TBList=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql)

$($("$DB"_TBList)=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql)

$($DB)_TBList)=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql)

"$($DB)_TBList"=(isql -S $DSQuery -U $User -P $PW -w 200 -D $DB -b -i $SQLDir\Get_TBList.sql)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Create a collection of custom PS objects. Add database name as one property and query results as another a property. A hashtable would work too, dbname as key and results as value. That would be much more manageable and future-proof.

Comment: So there is no easy way to do it like linux which would be:
$(DB)_TBList=